# Default Locale is not showing as href link in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony

I run Symfony 3.4 in my local and added locale in default and routes. Given below:

in `app/config.yml`

```
framework:
   default_locale:  "en"
```

in `Routes` I have

```
homepage:
   path:     /{_locale}
   defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Home:index, _locale: en }
```

and in twig I have:

```
{% set en_params = app.request.attributes.get('_route_params') | default([]) | merge(app.request.query) %}

{% set en_params = en_params | merge({'_locale': 'en'}) %}


<a href="{{ path('homepage', en_params ) }}" class="en"><span>English</span></a>
```

The expected output should be `http://localhost/en` when I will hover on anchor tag or click

but it is overriding with the default locale and showing `http://localhost`

Thanking you in advance to provide me the right way or correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if an optional parameter (the `{_locale}` parameter) is at an optional position (i.e. the end) and is also the default, it can (and apparently will) be omitted. The same is true for `{_format}` and even for `.{_format}` (additional dot)

I think, as long as it works, why do you care?

You can maybe force the parameter by explicitly defining the `_locale` requirement to be `[a-z]{2}` (or even more explicitly `de|en`) but I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: for home, a route like `/{_locale}` it is not showing `/en` if we set `en` as defalut

Comment: have you tried explicitly setting the requirement? - but anyway, why is it bothering you?

Comment: I want to change language according to country. like: for USA it will be `en` for Germany it will be `de`

Comment: and that *will* work. the route `/{_locale}` is special, since it *ends* with the optional parameter. with every other route like `/{_locale}/something` it will absolutely work.